# I have following the syntax error "Incorrect syntax near '*='."

Tags: sql-server

I tried to fix that code many times, i don't know that syntax is not valid for SQL Server 2012. So please fix it

```
WHERE 
    invoice_register.trans_type_id IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9) AND
    invoice_register.store_id = invoice_detail.store_id AND
    invoice_register.invoice_register_id = invoice_detail.invoice_register_id AND
    ii.item_id = invoice_detail.item_id AND
    ii.style_master_id *= sm.style_master_id AND /*Incorrect Syntax*/
    (@a_category_id = -9999 OR ii.category_id = @a_category_id ) AND
    (@a_store_id is NULL OR invoice_register.store_id = @a_store_id ) AND
    (invoice_register.trans_date between @a_Start_Date and @a_End_Date)) A
GROUP BY 
    A.store_id, A.category_id,
    A.type_id, A.item_id, A.item_code,
    A.name, A.cost, A.price_sold,
    A.manufacturer, A.style_number,
    A.comments, A.UPC
```

Please fix my syntax. I think my syntax is old

Comment: That is very, very old JOIN syntax, I suggest you go learn current methods

Comment: What is `*=`???  This is not Oracle.

Comment: "Please fix my syntax".  Where's your `JOIN`???

Comment: Please add your `FROM` / `JOIN` clause to the example. The replacement for `*=` goes there.

Comment: "I think my syntax is old" - you'd be right. Explicit ANSI join syntax was added to the standard in 1992. That's more than a quarter of a century ago! You should have had a chance to learn it by now, since it's also been supported in SQL Server for all of this millennium, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Three points here:

Firstly, You are showing us part of an subquery and the outer query - you should indent the subquery for readability.

Secondly, also on the topic of readability, you should use a more meaningful name than `A` for your subquery.

The main issue, as pointed out in the comments, is that you are using old non-ANSI-standard syntax to join your tables. Instead of putting that information in the `WHERE` clause, you should do that in the `JOIN` clause and leave the `WHERE` clause for actual record-level filter conditions.

Your from clause should look like this:

```
FROM
    invoice_register
    INNER JOIN invoice_detail ON invoice_register.invoice_register_id = invoice_detail.invoice_register_id
    INNER JOIN ii ON ii.item_id = invoice_detail.item_id
    LEFT JOIN sm ON ii.style_master_id = sm.style_master_id
```

You then remove all these conditions from the `WHERE` clause.

Presumably the ii and sm are aliases for inventory_item and style_master - adjust your FROM clause to suit.

Don't underestimate the point about the conceptual separation of filter conditions (`WHERE`) from join conditions (`FROM`) - and aggregate conditions (`HAVING`). It will be clearer for a reader when you indicate your intent.